# Netty handler removing itself

Tags: java, netty

I have a netty authentication handler that looks at the first message that comes in (HttpRequest),

If the request is authorized I then have the handler remove itself from the pipeline before sending the message upstream. However it seems that the next message still makes it to the handler. Is this expected?

Using netty 4.14

```
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object obj) throws Exception {
   if (!(obj instanceof HttpRequest)) {
    //Do not authenticate unknown object types.
    ReferenceCountUtil.release(obj);
    return;
  }

  HttpRequest httpRequest = (HttpRequest)obj;
  AuthenticatedInfo authenticatedInfo = Services.authenticationAuthority.authenticate(httpRequest, null);

  // check access
  if (authenticatedInfo.getMerchantId() == null) {
    sendUnauthorized(ctx);
    ReferenceCountUtil.release(obj);
  } else {
    ctx.pipeline().remove(this);
    ctx.fireChannelRead(httpRequest);
  }
}
```

Comment: Since HTTP is stateless, are you sure that the next message doesn't arrive in new channel (and thus, new pipeline)?

Comment: The next message is a LastHttpContent definitely on the same pipeline because it works when I add an authenticated boolean.

Comment: This should work... If it not work please create a reproducer / unit test and open up a bug report in our bug tracker.